Arctic Cat 440 Snowmobile — What mechanical gear to keep with me?
I am a new owner of an old Arctic Cat Panther Deluxe 440 F/C Snowmobile (2-stroke).
Intended use: 2km trips to a cabin on private land in eastern Ontario.


Snowmobiles are new territory for me. As are 2-stroke engines in general.
What kind of mechanical gear should I keep with me in case I have mechanical issues? Either gear to store in the machine's rear compartment or in my truck.

NGK BR9ES sparkplugs
Spark plug tool
Oil (separate reservoir)
Gas
Kill switch override (the kill switch is broken off, so I'm already using the override)
Anything else?

As @FDryer suggested, I have a sister post on the Great Outdoors Stack Exchange.

I'd assume you'd probably want a replacement belt along with whatever tools you'd need to replace it. I've not done much work on sleds, so I'll leave an "answer" to someone in the know.

For safety, a companion on another snowmobile. If not possible, snowshoes to walk back to safety if you can't get it running after a breakdown. Trying to walk any distance through waist deep powder is not fun. I'll leave the mechanical suggestions to others.

Talk to snowmobile owners. They're more likely to give sound advice on carrying spare parts and survival gear.

Perhaps some starting fluid. I have some cousins that were arctic cat guys and they had nothing but trouble with the things, they'd bring four and maybe two would run at any given time. My family had skidoos and never a single problem.
